# Python date series generation

Tags: python, pandas

In python, given a start date:Nov 2 ,2018 (Friday),
I need to generate a dataframe with a series of weekly dates and tag them as below:
Basically each date pair goes from one friday to next thursday and spans 1 week

```
START_DT    END_DT        WEEK_IND  MONTH_IND(same month as END_DT)
2018-11-01  2018-11-08     1         201811
2018-11-09  2018-11-15     2         201811
2018-11-16  2018-11-22     3         201811
2018-11-23  2018-11-29     4         201811
2018-11-30  2018-12-06     1         201812( WEEK_IND resets as it is a new month)
...
...
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "tag"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.date_range(start='20181102', end='20181231', freq='1w-FRI')
end = start + pd.DateOffset(6)

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'start': start, 'end': end, 'month': end.strftime('%Y%m')}, columns=['start', 'end', 'month'])
df['week'] = df.groupby('month').cumcount() + 1

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
       start        end   month  week
0 2018-11-02 2018-11-08  201811     1
1 2018-11-09 2018-11-15  201811     2
2 2018-11-16 2018-11-22  201811     3
3 2018-11-23 2018-11-29  201811     4
4 2018-11-30 2018-12-06  201812     1
5 2018-12-07 2018-12-13  201812     2
6 2018-12-14 2018-12-20  201812     3
7 2018-12-21 2018-12-27  201812     4
8 2018-12-28 2019-01-03  201901     1
```

Comment: Your date offset is incorrect.  The start is not guaranteed to be a friday, nor is the end guaranteed to be a thursday here.  For example, 11-17-2018 was a Saturday

Comment: @user3483203 You are right, but I believe that by "tag" the OP was referring to the count of the weeks. That is what is illustrated in this answer.

Comment: `dates = pd.date_range(start='20181102', end='20181231', freq='7D')` fixes this, right? Jumping seven days will always result in the same day of the week. Always. The real mistake is in the question; `2018-11-01` is the first entry in his expected dataframe but that's a Thursday.

Comment: @jorijnsmit You would need to create two separate date ranges for that to work.  A better approach would actually use `1w-FRI` as a frequency and then add `6` days to it to get the correct offset

Comment: @user3483203 Again; jumping seven days (`pd.DateOffset(7)`) will always result in the same day of the week, right? I don't see how it could go wrong.

Comment: Not if you give it an incorrect start date.  Also, explicit is better than implicit.  The frequency is there, and should be used over calculating an offset yourself.

Comment: @user3483203 Updated the answer to include your fixes. I agree with you explicit is better than implicit!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.tseries`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#parametric-offsets)

It has the `Week` offset for generating weekly data that accepts a weekday parameter and results in the generated dates always lying on a particular day of the week -

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
pd.to_datetime(df['START_DT']) + Week(weekday=3)
```

**Output**

```
0   2018-11-08
1   2018-11-15
2   2018-11-22
3   2018-11-29
4   2018-12-06
```

Comment: Huh, I've always just directly used `datetime.timedelta` but this seems better.